# Asp.Net Membership model GetUser returns null on local host

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am using asp.net `Membership.GetUser()` function, 
it works fine when I am making a request from web server, 
When I am trying to that from localhost, it always returns null. I have some idea that due to the request type, the function is unable to catch the current user. But I am not confident to conclude that. So any one can provide some information or a doc please

Comment: You have to give us some more details. Do you use a custom membership API implementation? Which way is used to authenticate your users? Forms authentication? Active directory (Windows authentication)?

Comment: I Use forms authentication